# get array value from std object in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below. I want to extract the values . Help me out please. But this doesn't print anything. Please help me.Any help would be appreciated.May you all find this question similar.But I am unable to find any answer,because that's the way we do to find the array values.

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bHeader] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ei] => NSE
                    [seg] => I
                )

            [cNetChangeIndicator] => 
            [fClosingIndex] => 10558.5
            [fHighIndexValue] => 10532
            [fIndexValue] => 10469
            [fLowIndexValue] => 10438.5
            [fOpeningIndex] => 10499.5
            [fPercentChange] => -0.85
            [sIndexName] => 962450
            [fChange] => -89.5
            [iIdxId] => 311
        )
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am printing like this                                                                                 echo $arr[0]['fIndexValue'];
echo $arr[0]['fChange'];
echo $arr[0]['fPercentChange'];

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the object in the array as if it is also an array.

You need to access the object's properties using `->`

```
echo $arr[0]->fIndexValue; 
echo $arr[0]->fChange; 
echo $arr[0]->fPercentChange';
```

For example:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->fIndexValue = 10469;

$arr = array();
$arr[0] = $obj;

echo $arr[0]->fIndexValue;
```

Prints "10469".

Comment: The script stops executing>I am getting a blank page

Comment: Updated answer above - does this make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

convert your object in to array using

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

if you use json_decode than give second parameter true e.g

```
$array = json_decode($jsonStr,TRUE);
```

It will return array so no need to typecast(conveting) obj to array

also used operator '->' which help to fetch data from object

Answer (score 0):

Try this to print the whole thing, assuming your var is $arr:

```
print_r($arr);
```

Or for variables

```
print($arr[0]-->fIndexValue);
```

Comment: fIndexValue,fChange,fPercentChange

Comment: print($arr[0]-->fIndexValue);

Comment: added the example